# regex replace : if not followed by letter or number

Tags: regex, string, lua, lua-patterns

Okay so I wanted a regex to parse uncontracted(if that's what it is called) ipv6 adresses

Example ipv6 adress: `1050:::600:5:1000::`

What I want returned: `1050:0000:0000:600:5:1000:0000:0000`

My try at this:

`ip:gsub("%:([^0-9a-zA-Z])", ":0000")`

The first problem with this: It replaces the first and second `:`

So `::` gets replaced with `:0000`

Replacing it with `:0000:` wouldn't work because then it will end with a `:`. Also this would note parse the newly added `:` resulting in: `1050:0000::600:5:1000:0000:`

**So what would I need this regex to do?**

Replace every `:` by `:0000` if it isn't followed by a number or letter

Main problem: `::` gets replaced instead of 1 `:`

Comment: There's [this](https://regex101.com/r/bW4xE0/1), but that won't work with Lua (I'm blanking on any ideas that would work).

Comment: Lua pattern matching is not standard regex.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` and other functions from Lua's string library use [Lua Patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) which are much simpler than regex. Using the pattern more than once will handle the cases where the pattern overlaps the replacement text. The pattern only needs to be applied twice since the first time will catch even pairings and the second will catch the odd/new pairings of colons. The trailing and leading colons can be handled separately with their own patterns.

```
ip = "1050:::600:5:1000::"
ip = ip:gsub("^:", "0000:"):gsub(":$", ":0000")
ip = ip:gsub("::", ":0000:"):gsub("::", ":0000:")
print(ip) -- 1050:0000:0000:600:5:1000:0000:0000
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no single statement pattern to do this but you can use a function to do this for any possible input:

```
function fill_ip(s)
  local ans = {}
  for s in (s..':'):gmatch('(%x*):') do
    if s == '' then s = '0000' end
    ans[ #ans+1 ] = s
  end
  return table.concat(ans,':')
end

--examples:
print(fill_ip('1050:::600:5:1000::'))
print(fill_ip(':1050:::600:5:1000:'))
print(fill_ip('1050::::600:5:1000:1'))
print(fill_ip(':::::::'))
```